# Reading an empty Textbox.Text as " ", null or String.Empty?

Tags: c#, null, string

This has always confused me when it comes to Text Boxes on a form. I know that a `string` can be `null` or `String.Empty`, but can a Text Box?

By my understanding, as soon as the control is created it automatically contains "text" (I use inverted commas because while there might not be text in the field, the field exists).

Therefore if a Text box is created, `TextBox.Text == null` and `TextBox.Text == String.Empty` are false?

Or is that not true, because `TextBox.Text` is the same as `string`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

from [TextBox.Text](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.textbox.text%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) documentation

> A string containing the text contents of the text box. The default is
>   an empty string ("").

Therefore if a Text box is created, `TextBox.Text` is not `null`, it is `String.Empty`

You can't set a `null` value to a control text, the setter of the Text property is implemented as below, As per the implementation `null` will be convert to `empty`

```
  set
  {
    if (value == null)
      value = "";
    if (value == this.Text)
      return;
    .....
```

Answer (score 1):

I tried:

```
public partial class MainWindow {
    public MainWindow() {
        InitializeComponent();
        Console.WriteLine("Text is empty:{0}", TextBox1.Text == string.Empty);
        Console.WriteLine("Text is null:{0}", TextBox1.Text == null);
        Console.WriteLine();

        Console.WriteLine("TextBox.Text = null")
        TextBox1.Text = null;
        Console.WriteLine("Text is empty:{0}", TextBox1.Text == string.Empty);
        Console.WriteLine("Text is null:{0}", TextBox1.Text == null);
    }
}
```

And I got:

```
Text is empty:True
Text is null:False

TextBox.Text = null
Text is empty:True
Text is null:False
```

So I guess TextBox.Text converts `null` into `String.Empty`.

Answer (score 0):

The `TextBox` is a class just like any other and it has a property called `Text` which is of type `string`.

So the `Text` property could be `null` or `String.Empty`.

You could think of it like this:

```
 public class TextBox :  Control 
 {
      public string Text {get; set;}
      // other properties ...
 }
```